# How to match string with rdd's field name

Tags: python, pyspark

In my pyspark 2.0.1 version I need to check if particular name[say client] appears in my rdd column name or not & generates an error message if that field, client, is not present in my data fame.Can you please suggest some syntax like below syntax

```
field='client'
field not in df.schema.fields:
print('field: ', field, "is not available)
```

Comment: is it rdd or dataframe?

Comment: Actually I was using pyspark data frame & I used df.columns statement & got error message that RDD object has no attribute 'columns'.

Comment: So, that means that, despite what you tried, `df` is not a dataframe but an rdd, which is important as rdd's don't have a `schema` attribute https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD

Comment: Yes, I know that rdd don't have schema attribute. I just put it to show that I need something which can match similar to that schema.fields way or in python terms df.columns way.

Comment: so, you want it to work with rdd's or dataframes??? And if for rdd's (which do not have columns, hence column names), where will be your field names (first line, perhaps?). A sample of your data will be most useful...

Comment: It will be helpful if you can suggest similar type of function for rdd as well as for dataframe for my future learning. I found schema.fields returns field in this format `StructField(client,StringType,true)` and I don't know how to retrieve client from this format

Comment: OK. I got the answer from you for rdd. can you please suggest for data frame portion which I mentioned in my previous comment? As I need to apply that logic so I'm feeling it is better to use dataframe

Comment: I found the solution for data frame.it is df.schema.names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **RDDs**:

```
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

# make some dummy data:
rdd = sc.parallelize([[u'mailid', u'age', u'address'], [u'satya', u'23', u'Mumbai'], [u'abc', u'27', u'Goa']])  # first element is the header
header = rdd.first()
header
# [u'mailid', u'age', u'address']

field = 'client'
if field not in header:
  print('field: '+ field + " is not available")
# field: client is not available
```

For **dataframes**:

```
# using the rdd defined above
# remove first line from data and use it as header:
df = rdd.filter(lambda row : row != header).toDF(header)
df.show()
# +------+---+-------+ 
# |mailid|age|address| 
# +------+---+-------+
# | satya| 23| Mumbai|
# |   abc| 27|    Goa|
# +------+---+-------+

header_df = df.schema.names
header_df
# ['mailid', 'age', 'address']

field = 'client'
if field not in header_df:
  print('field: '+ field + " is not available")
# field: client is not available
```